# dynamic url call same php page by htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

My site dynamic url like that "http://localhost/news/daily/2.shtml" but default page is "http://localhost/feed/news.php" I need to redirect all this dynamic url to this same page by access .

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^news/daily/\w+/\w+/?$ /feed/news.php [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

I have used that code for dynamic url.

Comment: Okay, and what have you tried?

Comment: What are other examples of dynamic URL?

Comment: Search for Rewrite URLs

Comment: i search that but can't find the solution  but now i have tried with this <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^news/daily/\w+/\w+/?$ /feed/news.php [L,NC]
</IfModule>

Answer (score 1):

Your regex won't match `/news/daily/2.shtml`.

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^news/daily/.+$ /feed/news.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404  I am getting this error

Comment: What URL do you enter in browser and what does it become before this error?